# Session stored variable got warning on log in

Tags: php, session, variables

I Have stored the session value like this on `header.php`

```
$order_total = $_SESSION['order_total'];
```

And I get a warning message every time I login

> Notice: Undefined index: order_total in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zzz\frontend\header.php on line 15

And once I go to that page again, the message was removed

Comment: Please check session is set or not if it is set then store in $order_total varriable else set null value in it,or provide me you code

Comment: Have you started the session in every file on the first line with `start_session()`?

Comment: Make sure you have started session using session_start(); before using session make sure you have  set $_SESSION['order_total'] before accessing it . If it doesn't work try turning on output buffering using ob_start() in the beginning

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check session first

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['order_total']) && !empty($_SESSION['order_total'])) {
   $order_total = $_SESSION['order_total'];
}else{
   $order_total = "session is not set";
}
```